# Could one today be blessed with the wisdom of Solomon and love of David?

Tags: king-david, king-solomon

I am a Muslim, And I would like to know what the Jewish perspective is about attaining the wisdom of Solomon (may peace and blessings be upon him) and the love for G_d of David (may peace and blessings be upon him).

Solomon was known to be a very wise king and judge. Also, according to our belief, David (may peace and blessings be upon him) used to fast on alternate days throughout the year, and had divine love.

Can a human being of the 21st century be blessed with such a wisdom as that of Solomon (may peace and blessings be upon him) and the divine love of David (may peace and blessings be upon him)?

Comment: This seems like it's three questions: 1. In the Jewish tradition, did David fast on alternating days throughout the year? 2. Can someone today have the wisdom or dominion of Solomon? 3. Can someone today be loved by G-d as much as David? Or 2 and three can be combined.

Comment: In answer to 1, it's actually forbidden to fast on a number of days - including the eight day holiday of Sukkot and the seven day holiday of Passover, so I'd assume we don't have that specific tradition, but we do have a tradition of David making true repentance for his affair with Bat'sheva.

Comment: As @CharlesKoppelman notes, this looks like three separate questions that seem to have little to do with one another. I'm closing this until it can be cleaned up.

Comment: @msh210, as has been noted, it's not clear what this is asking, and I think #2 can be extracted from it and allowed to stand alone in the "dupe" question.

Comment: @SethJ, you mean #1? The dupe question hasn't been closed. I'm not understanding you, I think.

Comment: @msh210, sorry. I was just pre-empting a closure of the other one. But I've just edited this one, so (I hope) both should be good now. Oh, and yes, #1. My bad.

Comment: Lets assume that David fasted alternately except for the holidays and shabbos.

Answer (score 1):

I had heard a rav in my community give a shiur on tefillah and ask why people don't pray that they should have a third eye. He answered that people don't really think they would get it, so why bother asking?

If you really think you can get the wisdom of Solomon or the love of David, pray for it. Anything is possible if you truly believe you can get it and G-d feels you earned it.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot attain the wisdom of Solomon, and probably not the love that David received either, but we can strive for these goals. This is similar to how one cannot attain levels of prophecy achieved by Moses (Maimonides 13 principles of jewish faith).

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Ilan, and thanks for the answer! I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us. If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). I saw some of your other answers, maybe you want to read ["A beginner’s guide to MY - How is this site different from other Judaism sites”](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites) particularly to understand MY focus on sources

Answer (score 0):

there is a concept of yerida hadorot (descent of the generations).

ex. The talmud in Shabbat 112b states:

> R. Zera said in Raba bar Zimuna's name: If the earlier [scholars] were
>   sons of angels, we are sons of men; and if the earlier [scholars] were
>   sons of men, we are like donkeys...

as the generations go further from sinai the wisdom decreases. This is why in the talmud a sage from the talmudic era is not allowed to argue with a sage from the mishnaic era. The latter is presumably on a much higher level of wisdom which is not attainable to the former. How much more so, for Solomon who was described back then as the wisest of all men.

As for love of David, he attained very high levels of prophecy which is a very deep level of communion with God. We have a tradition that the era of prophecy ended with the destruction of the temple. But make yourself as ready as possible at your level because it's supposed to return with the rebuilding of the temple.

Comment: Sources? E.g. for this "tradition" connecting prophecy to the Temple?

Answer (score 0):

The Bible is very clear that Solomon's wisdom exceeded that of any who came before or after him:

> Behold, I have done according to thy words: lo, I have given thee a wise and an understanding heart; so that there has been none like thee before thee, nor after thee shall any arise like thee. (Kings I 3:12)

As far as I am aware no such promise was given to King David. Mainly because
love of G-d is not something one is simply blessed with. Rather, it is something one works to achieve. However, the chances of a person reaching such a level seem remote to me, but one should still use King David and other righteous people as role models. (AFAIK, our tradition does not say King David fasted on alternate days. In addition, doing so would not necessarily prove love of G-d.)

Answer (score -1):

**Could one today be blessed with the wisdom of Solomon and love of David?**

Both David and Solomon had an open, humble, and sincere passion for God when they were young. Their blessings were in part for the purpose God had for them as well as what God offers all who seek him in truth.

Both David and Solomon grew distant from God as their interests became filled with matters of the flesh and the world.

Solomon gives words of instruction for those who would seek greater blessings from God.

> Proverbs 2:1-11  My son, if thou wilt receive my words, and hide my
>   commandments with thee;   So that thou incline thine ear unto wisdom,
>   and apply thine heart to understanding;   Yea, if thou criest after
>   knowledge, and liftest up thy voice for understanding;   If thou
>   seekest her as silver, and searchest for her as for hid treasures;
>   Then shalt thou understand the fear of the LORD, and find the
>   knowledge of God.   For the LORD giveth wisdom: out of his mouth
>   cometh knowledge and understanding.   He layeth up sound wisdom for
>   the righteous: he is a buckler to them that walk uprightly.   He
>   keepeth the paths of judgment, and preserveth the way of his saints.
>   Then shalt thou understand righteousness, and judgment, and equity;
>   yea, every good path.   When wisdom entereth into thine heart, and
>   knowledge is pleasant unto thy soul;   Discretion shall preserve thee,
>   understanding shall keep thee:

Some observations;

1. The “if/then” statements can be taken as promises from God open to those who seek him.
2. The earnestness described speaks to motivation and purpose in the heart of the seeker.
3. Love might be described as selflessness and be a measure of what we are willing to surrender to God.
4. Wisdom might be seen as a response from God to those whose hearts are humble, sincere, and and surrendered to him.

In regard to a quantity of love or wisdom, we may not need as much as Solomon or David as we are unlikely to be asked to rule nations. However, we can seek to live righteously in faith and dependence on God so that our love and devotion and his gift of wisdom can bless our families and all we may encounter.