# Did King David really fast on alternate days?

Tags: fast-days, king-david

Could you please let me know whether 
King David fasted on alternate days? Have you got this tradition in Judaism? Any historical reference?

Comment: He was known for fasting, in fact the Talmud says that he killed his evil inclination through his extensive fasting.  The Ben Ish Hai says that this means he fasted every(permissable) day for a number of years.  I just can't remember where he said it.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Your question would be clearer if it'd provide some basis for its conjecture, especially if that basis is founded in Judaism (e.g., "I heard from my Jewish friend..."). (That is, why are you asking whether he fasted alternate days rather than, for example, whether he danced alternate days?)

Comment: related (dupe?): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20556/could-one-pray-to-hashem-to-bless-him-with-the-wisdom-and-reign-of-solomon-and-l

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, as the other is unclear (and has been closed), I think the dupe part can be removed from the other one and allowed to stand here on its own.

Comment: David was known for fasting; [Psalms 109:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.109.24?lang=bi) says, "My knees are weak from fasting, my body is thin and gaunt." Also when his son by Bathsheba was sick David spent a week fasting ([2Samuel 12:16](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.12.16?lang=bi)).

Comment: Abdullah ibn Amr reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Verily, the most beloved fasting to Allah is the fasting of David and the most beloved prayer to Allah is the prayer of David, upon him be peace. He would sleep half of the night and stand in prayer for a third of it and then sleep for a sixth of it. He would fast every other day.”